# No rule to make object files based on pattern

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Hello I am trying to build my C++ project. I currently have a makefile that lists out all the names of the .o files I want to make. Then I prefix the directory onto them where I want them to be compiled to. Finally, I have two basic rules that handle building each object file then the executable from those object files. For whatever reason, make is not recognizing the pattern. Here is the makefile

```
CXX=g++
SRC_DIR=/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/Cosimulation/SystemC/Xilinx/lib
INC_DIR=-I/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/Cosimulation/SystemC/Xilinx/include
INC_DIR += -I/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/SystemC/systemc-2.3.2/include

LIB_DIR=-L/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/SystemC/system-2.3.2/lib-linux64
LIB_TAGS=-lsystemc

OBJ_DIR=/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/Cosimulation/Adder_PL/obj

ZYNQ_DEMO=/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/Cosimulation/Adder_PL/bin/zynq_demo
ZYNQMP_DEMO=/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/Cosimulation/Adder_PL/bin/zynqmp_demo

OBJS+ = memory.o trace.o debugdev.o demo-dma.o xilinx-zynq.o xilinx-zynqmp.o
OBJS += safeio.o remote-port-proto.o remote-port-sk.o remote-port-tlm.o
OBJS += remote-port-tlm-memory-master.o remote-port-tlm-memory-slave.o
OBJS += remote-port-tlm-wires.o

_ZYNQ_OBJS=zynq_demo.o
_ZYNQMP_OBJS=zynqmp_demo.o

_ZYNQ_OBJS += $(OBJS)
_ZYNQMP_OBJS += $(OBJS)

ZYNQ_OBJS=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR)/, $(_ZYNQ_OBJS))
ZYNPMP_OBJS=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/, $(_ZYNQMP_OBJS))

$(info $(ZYNQ_OBJS))

all: $(ZYNQ_DEMO) $(ZYNQMP_DEMO)

$(ZYNQ_DEMO): $(ZYNQ_OBJS)

$(ZYNQMP_DEMO): $(ZYNQMP_OBJS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc
    $(CXX) $(INC_DIR) $(LIB_DIR) $(LIB_TAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

I am getting the error:

> make: *** No rule to make target
>   `/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/Cosimulation/Adder_PL/obj/zynq_demo.o', needed
>   by`/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/Cosimulation/Adder_PL/bin/zynq_demo'. 
>   Stop.

The fourth rule should take care of zynq_demo.o correct. Why is it not recognizing a rule it can use to build that object file?

Comment: The easier way is using `$(vpath)` and not to specify the source directories explicitly at all.

Comment: Do you have a corresponding .cc file in the source directory, `/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/Cosimulation/SystemC/Xilinx/lib`?

Comment: no, that was the problem. I was not aware that it would complain about no rule even if it could find the target file name in the list

Comment: Did you really mean to write `OBJS+ = memory.o`... in your makefile? Not a syntax error, but not what you want either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of pattern rules.
When and where they apply is a little haphazard for my tastes.
A better alternative IMHO is *[static pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern)*.
To use these simply prefix your pattern rules with the targets that those patterns apply to.

So

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc
    $(CXX) $(INC_DIR) $(LIB_DIR) $(LIB_TAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

simply becomes

```
${ZYNC_OBJS}: $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cc
    $(CXX) $(INC_DIR) $(LIB_DIR) $(LIB_TAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

I can't tell because I don't have your source tree,
but I suspect *make* will now give you a different error.
Something about `/home/epi/jfrye_xilinx/Cosimulation/SystemC/Xilinx/lib/zynq_demo.cc` being missing maybe (???).